# Including HTML arrow in a button

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am designing an HTML email and would like to include a right arrow on a HTML button, and I resorted to using special character and transform-rotate it.

My question is, right now they appear on different lines. How do I wrap the text and the arrow to appear only in one line? I tried using `whitespace:no-wrap` on the td element, but that does not seem to do the trick. Below is the code snippet.

```html
<tr>
    <td class="call-to-action" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="call-to-action1" value="Schedule Online Here" style="white-space:nowrap">SCHEDULE ONLINE HERE
            <h1 class="little-arrow" style="-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);transform: rotate(270deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */; color: white; font-size:14px">&#8711</h1></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow is breaking in next line - because you are using `h1` for the arrow which is a block element. Simply use `span` and it will be in one line.

```html
<tr>
    <td class="call-to-action" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="call-to-action1" value="Schedule Online Here" style="white-space:nowrap">SCHEDULE ONLINE HERE
            <span class="little-arrow" style="-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);transform: rotate(270deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */; color: white; font-size:14px; display: inline-block">&#8711</span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Using `h1`** The same layout can be achieved by using same `h1` tag. simply use `display:inline-block` to bring them in one line -

```css
.button,
.little-arrow {
  display: inline-block
}

.little-arrow {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  ;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="call-to-action" align="center">
    <button type="button" class="call-to-action1" value="Schedule Online Here">SCHEDULE ONLINE HERE
      <h1 class="little-arrow">&#8711;</h1></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: while this solves the line problem, it causes the rotate to not work (e.g. arrow is pointing downward again). Am I doing something wrong here? Does rotate only work on block element?

Comment: changing the display to inline-block works, thank you!